# Cannot get all Routes from A to E in a directed graph

Tags: javascript, graph, directed-graph

I am having some troubles getting all the routes in the graph. It works for some, but clearly something is off since it cannot get all the routes from A to E.

```js
let graph = {
    'A': ['B', 'D', 'E'],
    'B': ['C'],
    'C': ['D', 'E'],
    'D': ['C', 'E'],
    'E': ['B']
};

function search(start, end, graph) {
    
    let queue = [...graph[start]];
    let visited =  [];
    while (queue.length) {
      count = 1;
      let node = queue.shift();
      if (graph[node]){
          let answer = recursiveStep(node, end, graph, str = node, visit = new Set(), nodes = []);
          if (answer){
            visited.push(answer);
          }
      }
    }
    return visited;
}

function recursiveStep(start, end, graph, str, visit, nodes) {   
    if (end === start) {
        if (str.length <= 3 && !visit.has(str)) {
            visit.add(str)
            return str};
    }
    if (str.length > 3) return str = ""; 
    nodes.push(...graph[start])
    while (nodes.length) {
        start = nodes.shift();
        str += start
        return recursiveStep(start, end, graph, str, visit, nodes)
    }
    return visit
}


console.log(search('A', 'E', graph));
```

The output is [ 'DCE', 'E' ], however since I need all routes less than or equal to 3. It should be: [ 'BCE', 'DCE', 'DE', 'E' ]. The code works if you want to copy and paste it using node. Maybe there is a bug, not too sure, but I've also tried to do it iteratively.

Comment: Debugging is a critical skill to develop as you learn how to program. I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips and tricks to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a smaller approach where you iterate the actual node and omit longer pathes and visited items.

Then check if not reached the end and iterate the next node.

Or push the result.

```js
function search(start, end, graph) {
    function iter(node, visited) {
        graph[node].forEach(n => {
            if (visited.length > 2 || visited.includes(n)) return;
            if (n !== end) return iter(n, [...visited, n]);
            result.push([...visited, n].join(''));                
        });
    }
    
    var result = [];
    iter(start, []);
    return result;
}


let graph = { A: ['B', 'D', 'E'], B: ['C'], C: ['D', 'E'], D: ['C', 'E'], E: ['B'] };

console.log(search('A', 'E', graph));
```